# Java two dimensional Array of ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

For school I have to make a voting program according to the Dutch voting system where there are parties which have candidates. For this program I have made a class "Candidate" which has a getter and setter for the name of the candidate. Then there is a class "Party" which contains:

```
ArrayList<Candidate>CandidateList
```

and a method to add candidates by name. Next, I made a class "PartyList" which contains:

```
ArrayList<Party>Parties
```

and this method:

```
public void addParty(Party party){
    Parties.add(new Party());
```

I thought it would be better to do it like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Party>>Parties
```

but my teacher said it would be enough to make a one dimensional ArrayList. Now comes the part where I get lost:

I have another class "Voting" in which the final voting takes place, but for that i have to make a two-dimensional array of the parties and candidates that will look like this:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
3 1
etc.
```

In which the first column represents the party and the second represents the candidate. I know that the first column would be possible by using Parties.size() but the second column wouldn't be possible this way because there are more than one Arraylists of CandidateList. How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Your `Party` class contains only one `ArrayList<Candidate>`, so you can get all the `Candidate`s if you have the `Party`. And you can go through your `ArrayList<Party>` to get all parties...

Comment: what is it that you actually want to do? What do you mean by *more than one Arraylists of CandidateList*? Does each `Party` have more than one `CandidateList`? The 2 dimensional array you have shown, what is it? Is it the data to input to your program? Or it is just printing the parties and the candidates each party has?

Comment: Every party has one candidate list so, like Florian mentioned, i think i can access all candidates from a party by going through the list of parties. Problem is, I don't know how to do that. Should I do that by using a for-each loop? The two-dimensional array I show at the end is indeed just printing the parties and its candidates. However, I have to make a method that randomly gives candidates from different parties votes (50 in total) and that's where the array is going to be used. I hope this makes it a bit understandable..

Answer (score 0):

```
class Poll {
private Integer label;
private Integer value;

// Constructor or setter
public void Poll(Integer label, Integer value) {
    if (label == null || value == null) {
        return;
    }
    this.label = label;
    this.value = value;
}

// getters

public Integer getLabel() {
    return this.label;
}

public Integer getValue() {
    return this.value;
}
```

}

use it like this to store 2 items rather than multidimensional stuff

```
private ArrayList<Poll> items = new ArrayList<Poll>();
items.add(new Stuff(label, value));
 for (Poll item: items) {
 doSomething(item.getLabel()); // returns Integer      
 doSomething(item.getValue()); // returns Integer
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the exercise specifically mentions to make a candidate which has a position on a partylist and then add that party to an electoral list of a certain year.. The teacher already approved my main class which is like this:

       Party cda= new Party();
       cda.voegKandidaatToe("Henry");
       
       ElectoralList list2015=new ElectoralList();
       list2015.addParty(cda);